# How can I install only the proxmox kernel on Debian on Wheezy

Tags: debian, kernel, openvz, debian-wheezy, proxmox

I'm going to run two servers with OpenVZ on Wheezy. Since there are sadly no OpenVZ kernels in debian anymore I want to use the Proxmox kernel instead.

I'm doing all replication with scripts I have already in place. What I don't want is all the pve cluster stuff which in my case only gets in the way.

But if I try to install `vzctl` I get the whole pve cluster stuff if I want it or not.

How can I install only the proxmox kernel without it?

EDIT:
Which packages do I need from proxmox and can I mix them with the wheezy packages? Does vzctl from Wheezy work with proxmox kernel? How can I make shure to only get the packages I need from proxmox and not the ones I don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using proxmox at all.

While I was trying to install proxmox the people at openvz decided to provide their own debian kernel which is - like the proxmos kernen - a repackaged RedHat kernel. This is bundled with all the needed tools and all you have to do ist add:

```
deb http://download.openvz.org/debian wheezy main
```

to your sources list.

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but seems like a fairly simple solution.

Add the repos:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
+ deb http://download.proxmox.com/debian wheezy pve-no-subscription
```

Download the kernel image and header.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install pve-kernel-2.6.32-28-pve pve-headers-2.6.32-28-pve
```

Remove the repos:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
- deb http://download.proxmox.com/debian wheezy pve-no-subscription
```

If you need to dig around for updates to the kernel, and forgot the naming convention they were using, you can just check the repos online, or use an *apt-cache show*.

ProxMox repo:
http://download.proxmox.com/debian/dists/wheezy/pve-no-subscription/binary-amd64/

Comment: I think that [package pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) may be a better idea than removing the repository after installation, that way you would still be able to get updates.

Comment: Agreed. If I have some more time later I might look into updating this.

Comment: Meanwhile I found out that the 3.0 version of vzctl which comes with wheezy is to old for the kernel. So you have to find a different solution. Mine was to use the kernel from openvz.org.

Comment: I'm still crossing my fingers that proxmox will implement lxc support, alas, they seem to be more red-hat oriented.

Answer (score 1):

Largely taken from [here](http://wiki.openvz.org/Install_kernel_from_RPM_on_Debian_6.0):

Get the latest kernel and utils. You need

```
vzkernel
vzkernel-devel
vzctl-core
vzctl
ploop-lib
ploop
vzquota
```

vzkernel-devel is optional.

```
cd /tmp
wget http://download.openvz.org/kernel/branches/rhel6-2.6.32/042stab076.8/vzkernel-2.6.32-042stab076.8.x86_64.rpm
wget http://download.openvz.org/kernel/branches/rhel6-2.6.32/042stab076.8/vzkernel-devel-2.6.32-042stab076.8.x86_64.rpm
wget http://download.openvz.org/utils/vzctl/4.3.1/vzctl-4.3.1-1.x86_64.rpm
wget http://download.openvz.org/utils/vzctl/4.3.1/vzctl-core-4.3.1-1.x86_64.rpm
wget http://download.openvz.org/utils/ploop/1.7/ploop-1.7-1.x86_64.rpm
wget http://download.openvz.org/utils/ploop/1.7/ploop-lib-1.7-1.x86_64.rpm
wget http://download.openvz.org/utils/vzquota/3.1/vzquota-3.1-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Install the following packages...

```
apt-get install fakeroot alien libcgroup1
```

... and convert the RPM packages to DEB packages:

```
fakeroot alien --to-deb --scripts --keep-version vz*.rpm ploop*.rpm
```

Install the DEB packages as follows:

```
dpkg -i vz*.deb ploop*.deb
```

If you're having problem about overwriting files from other packages, try adding `--force-overwrite` option.

Make OpenVZ load on boot:

```
update-rc.d vz defaults
update-rc.d vzeventd defaults
```

Comment: I think this is the link you meant: http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-and-using-openvz-on-debian-wheezy-amd64 (Your link is the Squeeze Howto.) But this doesn't solve the problem of installing the Proxmox-Kernel and tools.